# size of class name vs size of an instance of the class

Tags: c++

```
class test {
 public:
 int a;
};

int main(){
 test t;
 //
 return ;
}
```

In the above example, is it correct to say `sizeof(test)` is always equal to `sizeof(t)`?

Comment: Yes. That said, when `sizeof` is applied to an expression, no parentheses are needed (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the reference for [sizeof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof), the two ways this operator can be used are:

> `sizeof` `(` *type* `)`
>
> 1. Yields the size in bytes of the object representation of type.
>
> `sizeof` *expression*
>
> 2. Yields the size in bytes of the object representation of *the type of expression*, if that expression is evaluated.

In your example with `sizeof(t)`, the type of the expression `t` is in fact `test`, and so the result will be exactly the same as the result of `sizeof(test)`.

Comment: Interesting. Would an upcasted instance of a derived class have the size of the upcasted class or the derived class?

Comment: @lennarthautzer it depends entirely on the *expression* used as an argument to `sizeof`.

Comment: I'm confused on the term `expression`. isn't `t` a variable? I thought an expression `is a sequence of operators and their operands`?

Comment: @Dan An *expression* can contain just a single variable such as `t`. It doesn't have to be more complicated to be an expression.

Comment: Thanks, so any variable could be called an expression as well?

Comment: @Dan Not exactly. Variables and expressions are different things, but yes, an expression can contain just a single variable.